# Why does Java 'break' statement not working?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    
    int length; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println(" How many dates would you like to include for the expiration dates notification? ");
    length=scanner.nextInt();  
    String[] dates = new String[length]; 
    System.out.println(" input date, formatting is hh:mm:ss");
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)  
    {
    dates[i]=scanner.next(); 
    }
    
    System.out.println("== DATE LIST =="); 
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)   
    {  
    System.out.println(dates[i]); 
    }  
    
    int loopcount;
            System.out.print("Please enter how much notification you would like to put in: ");
            loopcount = input.nextInt();
            
    
    System.out.println("== EXPIRE LIST ==\n"); 
    while (true) { 
        for (String z : dates) { 
            Thread.sleep(50); 

            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            Date convertednow = Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); 
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 
            String strnow = dateFormat.format(convertednow); 

            if (strnow.equals(z)) { 
                System.out.print(z+" has expired\n"); 
               
                
                
            
            int i = 0;                
            while(i < loopcount) { 
                System.out.println("Notification stopped");
                i++;
                if (i == 3) {
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I am new to Java. Sorry if I made a lot of mistakes.
What I was trying to do is make a timer that will notify the user when the certain time has reached. The user will input the timer via Scanner. My plan is when all of the timers that I input earlier has been notified, it will stop and give the message "Notification Stop" in the last line of the output. The problem that I am currently facing right now is whenever I am trying to stop the loop by using break statement. It just won't work and it will keep stuck in an infinite loop until I force it to stop.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: The `break` will only break out of your *inner* loop.

Comment: `break` only leaves the innermost loop. Don't use `while(true)` but instead check for a boolean value `while(running)` which you set to `false` before you reach your `break`

Comment: Or you can break to a line label.

Comment: Side note:  You can create a Date instance which represents the current date and time using just `new Date()`.  If all you want is a Date object, you don’t need to use LocalDateTime, ZoneId, or Instant at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` statement exits the inner-most loop, i.e. the `while(i < loopcount)` loop, not the middle `for (String z : dates)` loop or the outer `while (true)` loop.

If you want `break` to exit the outer loop, you can do it by using a **label**:

```java
System.out.println("== EXPIRE LIST ==\n");
MAIN: while (true) { // <== Added label 'MAIN'
    for (String z : dates) {
        Thread.sleep(50);

        . . .

        int i = 0;
        while(i < loopcount) {
            System.out.println("Notification stopped");
            i++;
            if (i == 3) {
                break MAIN; // <== Exit loop labeled 'MAIN'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* Some people highly discourage the use of labels, because it behaves similar to `goto` statements in other languages, and is considered bad for the code structure.

You can also use a `return` statement, if there is no code after the `while (true)` loop. Somewhat same argument against that (code structure).

Alternative is to use a `boolean` variable.

```java
System.out.println("== EXPIRE LIST ==\n");
boolean done = false;
while (! done) { // <== Exit outer loop when "done"
    for (String z : dates) {
        Thread.sleep(50);

        . . .

        int i = 0;
        while(i < loopcount) {
            System.out.println("Notification stopped");
            i++;
            if (i == 3) {
                done = true;
                break; // <== Exit inner while-loop
            }
        }
        if (done)
            break; // <== Exit for-loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by putting a `label` on the outer while and breaking on that label.  A break normally only applies to to the `immediate loop` in which it is executed.  So the `inner break` only breaks out of the `inner while loop`.

Another option is to use setable `boolean` in the loops and then conditionally set them to false to control when they will stop.

```
System.out.println("== EXPIRE LIST ==\n"); 
outer:
while (true) { 
    for (String z : dates) { 
        Thread.sleep(50); 
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        Date convertednow = 
             Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 
        String strnow = dateFormat.format(convertednow); 
        if (strnow.equals(z)) { 
            System.out.print(z+" has expired\n");         
        
        int i = 0;                
        while(i < loopcount) { 
            System.out.println("Notification stopped");
            i++;
            if (i == 3) {
                break outer;
            }         
        }      
    }
}
```